# How to know in which version a java bug was fixed

Tags: java

I am trying to workaround the following bug:
https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7019384

in the bug DB the status is closed and the fix version is 7(b138).
How can I know if my version which is 7u21 contains the fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag responsibly.  The "fix" tag is for FIX protocol, not for any generic fix to something.  Furthermore, your tags "bugs" and "beta" are useless; no one follows those, and they are not useful to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to have made it to [JDK7 Milestone 13](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/m13/changes/) (search by bug ID 7019384). Looks like you're good.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that they only made it worse.